# Error while installing robotframework -ride

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, robotframework

I'm new to Python and have been trying to install some packages with pip.

I have gone through this sequence-------------

Download Python 2.7.15 from

```
https://www.python.org/downloads/

PATH = C:C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts 
(Is this we have to set in User Variable or System Variable?)
```

Then download wxPython from this link (Download this version wxPython2.8-win64-unicode-2.8.12.1-py27)

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/
```

Then

Download setuptools (setuptools-39.2.0.zip) for Python from

```
https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/#files
```

Then

Download PIP files (pip-10.0.1.tar.gz) from

```
https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files
```

Now Extract the Setuptools

After extracting from the same folder TYPE "cmd" it will open then run this commend

```
"python setup.py install"
```

Now Extract the PIP files

After extracting from the same folder TYPE "cmd" it will open then run this commend

```
"pip install robotframework"
```

On the cmd run these commends one-by-one

```
pip install robotframework-ride
pip install robotframework-selenium2library
pip install selenium
pip install decorator
pip install docutils
pip install xlrd
pip install xlwt
pip install xlutils
pip install pigments
```

But pip install robotframework-ride unroll gives me

```
D:\Python\pip-10.0.1\pip-10.0.1>pip install robotframework-ride
Collecting robotframework-ride
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/14/a5f97f5cf5e981f01e8
c0b4c405b0dfc9bc86500cabb044d2c462f73004a/robotframework-ride-1.5.2.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Deeksha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f5wsnk57\robotframew
 ork-ride\setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    execfile(join(ROOT_DIR, 'src', 'robotide', 'version.py'))
 NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined

 ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Deeksha\
  AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f5wsnk57\robotframework-ride\
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `execfile` was removed in Python 3. Please make sure you run `pip` with Python 2.7, not Python 3. Start with `pip --version`.

Comment: I have installed python 2.7.15 and I am running pip through it. Can we have further suggestion?

Comment: The error comes from Python 3. Please show the result of `pip --version`.

Comment: Below is the result of cmd pip --version                                                                               
**C:\Users\Deeksha>pip --version
pip 9.0.3 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)**

Comment: @phd can you please suggest now?

Comment: Alas, no, I don't understand what's going on. `execfile` is a builtin function in Python 2 and cannot be not defined; but it was removed in Python 3. Let's see: you have downloaded `pip-10.0.1.tar.gz` but your `pip --version` reported 9.0.3. I'm sure you have at least 2 versions of Python, 2.7 and 3. The error came from Python 3.

Comment: @phd it's seems here is Miniconda installed in system, not sure but this could be the cause of error. I have Uninstalled it and tried again which shows me successful installation message of Ride.